# Two Coupled First Order Differential Equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, boundary-conditions

[image: ODES and their boundary conditions]

I'm trying to solve the following differential equations. The 4 boundary conditions imposed are based on physical grounds required for regularity at the origin. It is known that these equations do not have an analytic solution. Since these are two first-order equations, I need to specify only two boundary conditions to get the solution. I'm facing the following issue. In Mathematica, if I insert these equations using NDSolve, I need to impose two initial value or boundary value conditions. Ideally, out of the 4 boundary conditions that arise physically, I should be able to choose any 2 of them and I should get the correct graphs for $f(r)$ and $\phi (r)$. If I impose the boundary conditions $f(0.0001) = 1$ and $f(10) = 0$, then I get the correct graphs satisfying all 4 boundary conditions. Attached figure:[image: Correct graphs satisfying all 4 boundary conditions, having specified only 2]

```
s1 = NDSolve[{ f'[r] ==  r ((\[Phi][r])^2 - 1), 
   r  \[Phi]'[r] ==  \[Phi][r] f[r], f[0.0001] == 1, 
   f[10] == 0}, {\[Phi], f}, {r, 0.0001, 10}]
Plot[Evaluate[f[r] /. s1], {r, 0.0001, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[\[Phi][r] /. s1], {r, 0.0001, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

. Out of the 4 boundary conditions, if I pick any other combination of two conditions, I get "incorrect " graphs in the sense that they don't satisfy all 4 boundary conditions which, once again, are required to be satisfied on physical grounds. For example if I pick the boundary conditions as $\phi(0.0001)=0$ and $\phi(10) = 1$, then I get the following graphs[image: Graphs not satisfying the remaining boundary conditions]

```
s2 = NDSolve[{ f'[r] ==  r  ((\[Phi][r])^2 - 1), 
   r \[Phi]'[r] ==  \[Phi][r] f[r], \[Phi][10] == 
    1, \[Phi][0.0001] == 0}, {\[Phi], f}, {r, 0.0001, 10}]
Plot[Evaluate[f[r] /. s2], {r, 0.0001, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[\[Phi][r] /. s2], {r, 0.0001, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

. A similar issue holds if I pick any other combination of two boundary conditions. Does only the first combination seem to work? Is there a way in which I can make this more robust in the sense that I can feed in any two of the 4 boundary conditions and I get the right graphs? Maybe asymptotic stitching at the origin and at infinity?

Comment: Please also post some copiable codes that you have tried (e.g., those in your screenshot, but just making them copiable), so that potential helpers can start readily.

Comment: These initial conditions are not mutually compatible. You can not simply picking 2 of them. Consider e.g.:    phi[end]=1, f[end]=0.  Obviously phi=1, f=0 is a solution. This is incompatible with other initial conditions.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that standard numerical algorithms used to solve thise equations become numerically unstable for certain choices of the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. I have asked a follow up question [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263537/solving-coupled-ode-by-analyzing-solution-near-zero ), regarding picking up the first two boundary conditions and then stitching the near zero solution and varying a single parameter to get the desired behaviour. Can this approach be taken ? Advice would be greatly appreciated.