# Solving coupled ODE by analyzing solution near zero

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion, boundary-conditions

This question is related to an earlier question I had asked, [regarding coupled first order odes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263465/two-coupled-first-order-differential-equations). I'll add the system of odes with their boundary conditions again here. [image].

The comments for the previous post were helpful.

I was wondering  if the following could be done. Start with the first two boundary conditions and impose them at $r=0$, namely,$ \phi(0)=0 $and $f(0)=1$. We know how the functions behave close to zero: $\phi(r) = c_1*r+c_2*r^2+... $and  $f(r)= 1+f_1 * r+ f_2*r^2+..$. If we perform this Taylor expansion around zero and plug it into the coupled system, we generate a recursion relation between the coefficients $c_n$ and $f_n$. All these coefficients can be expressed as a function of $c_1$. I tried this by hand upto $O(r^5)$. If we consider the value of these Taylor expanded functions at some $r=0.01$ and use that as the initial condition for my system of ODEs, can I try and sweep over the free parameter $c_1$ so as to get the desired behaviour I want.

I'm attaching the desired graphs which satisfy all four conditions [image]. I've been trying to do this "sweeping" on Mathematica in the following manner. The $c$ used in the code is the same as the $c_1$ coefficient I'm referring to here in the text :

```
f[c_, r_] := 1 - (1/2) r^2 + (c^2/4  ) r^4 - (c^2/12) r^6
\[Phi][c_, r_] := c*r - (c/4) r^3 + ((c^3/16) + c/32) r^5
soln = ParametricNDSolve[{f'[r] == 
    r  (\[Phi][r]^2 - 1), \[Phi]'[r] ==  f[r] \[Phi][r]/r, 
   f[0.1] == f[c, 0.1], \[Phi][0.1] == \[Phi][c, 0.1]}, {\[Phi], 
   f}, {r, 0.1, 10}, c]
```

and

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[f[c][r] /. soln, {c, 0.84, 0.85, 0.001}]], {r, 
  0.1, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}]
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[\[Phi][c][r] /. soln, {c, 0.84, 0.85, 0.001}]], {r, 0.1, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 2}]
```

For c lying between 0.84 and 0.85, I get the following graphs:
[image]

and for c lying between 0.85 and 0.86 I get the following graphs:
[image]

So I know that c should lie somewhere in this regime but I do not know of a way to isolate the number. Also, from fig.3, we can see that $\phi(r)$ approaches its desired behaviour better than $f(r)$.Unfortunately, I do not know of an efficient way to get my desired graphs by varying c.

Comment: This seems like an ideal problem to be solved by applying a root-finding algorithm like the [bisection method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method). You’d set the x-coordinate for which you want to find the “root”, that is, where the function should go to zero. Then, choose two points along c that lie on either side of this zero (you already have these!) and use these to begin the finding the root via the bisection method. Such a method can be coded by hand, or likely the built-in root finding functions can be used.

Comment: If $\phi\rightarrow0$ as $r\rightarrow0$, I don't see how `phi[c_, r_]` can have the `c/r` term. It goes to infinity at $r=0$ unless $c=0$. And $c=0$ would seem to correspond to the solution $f(r)=1=r^2/2,\;\phi(r)=0$. You wrote $c_1*r\dots$ above the code. Is there a mistake?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @MichaelE2. I have corrected it. I tried running the corrected code and I got better graphs. But unfortunately, as stated in the edit, I'm still finding it a bit challenging to isolate the constant c which will give me the desired graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of starting at the singular point, why not start at the other end?

One trick to dealing with a singular point in the formula for a derivative is to use `Piecewise` to give the numeric value of the derivative at the singular point and use the formula elsewhere.  The trouble here is that we don't seem to know the derivative at `r == 0`, but we could try to solve for it. One nice thing about the ODE system is that it's likely going to force $\phi(r)\rightarrow0$ as $r\rightarrow0$.  So what we'll do is make a guess what $\phi'(0)$ will be -- I don't believe it has to be very close, since it will only make a difference in the last integration step -- and then iteratively adjust the initial condition at `r == 10` to shoot for the boundary condition at `r == 0` and update the derivative value after each step. (We estimate the derivative $\phi'(0)$ by the solution at `r == 10^-6` because the derivative at zero is set equal to the current estimate and would never change.  This introduces a small error, but singular points are difficult.)

```
ClearAll[f, ϕ, r, c, ϕp];
sys = {
   f'[r] == r (ϕ[r]^2 - 1),
   ϕ'[r] == Piecewise[{
      {f[r] ϕ[r]/r, r > 0}
      }, ϕp],  (* value at r == 0 *)
   f[10] == f0, ϕ[10] == ϕ0};
ϕp = 1.; (* educated(?) guess; set AFTER sys *)
obj[a0_?NumericQ] := Block[{a = a0, b = 1 - 0 1*^-8},
   soln = 
    ParametricNDSolve[sys, {ϕ, f}, {r, 0, 10}, {f0, ϕ0},
     AccuracyGoal -> 12, (* makes it strive for ϕ[0] == 0 *)
     Method -> {"Extrapolation", Method -> "LinearlyImplicitEuler"},
     InterpolationOrder -> All];
   ϕp = D[ϕ[a, b][r] /. soln, r] /. 
     r -> (ϕ[a, b]["Domain"] /. soln)[[1, 1]] + 1*^-6;
   f[a, b][0] /. soln
   ];
logf0 = a /. FindRoot[obj[Exp@a] == 1, {a, -5, -6}] (* Exp keeps parameter >0 *)

(*  -11.3726  *)

Block[{a = Exp@logf0, b = 1 - 0 1*^-8},
 Plot @@ {{f[a, b][r], ϕ[a, b][r]} /. soln, 
   Flatten@{r, f[a, b]["Domain"] /. soln},
   PlotLabel -> 
    Row[{f[0] == (f[a, b][0] /. soln), 
      ", ", ϕ[0] == (ϕ[a, b][0] /. soln)}]}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It was helpful. I did try and find the value of $c$ by the method I had outlined. But I had to use "Manipulate" to decrease the window of possibilities and I had to go till the twelfth decimal place to make sure that the functions asymptote to their values at infinity. If there's a way to automate this process, it would be very helpful as well. I appreciate the present solution as well.